# Pandas_TA giving error when using Binance API

Tags: pandas, binance, binance-api-client, pandas-ta

I am trying to calculate Bollinger Bands using Pandas_TA

(i) Data obtained from yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
from ta.volatility import BollingerBands
AMBEV = yf.download('ABEV3.SA', start = '2020-01-01', interval = '1d')
indicator_bb = BollingerBands(AMBEV['Adj Close'], window=20, window_dev=2)
AMBEV['bb_bbm'] = indicator_bb.bollinger_mavg()
BBH = indicator_bb.bollinger_hband()[-1]
AMBEV['bb_bbl'] = indicator_bb.bollinger_lband()
```

(ii) Data obtained from Binance API

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)
klines = client.get_historical_klines(TRADE_SYMBOL, TIME_INTERVAL, "1 day ago UTC", limit=30)
for candles in range(len(klines)-1):
    closes.append(float(klines[candles][4]))
closes = pd.DataFrame(closes, column='Close')    
if len(closes) > 21:
     bb = BollingerBands(closes, window=20, window_dev=2)
     closes['bb_h'] = bb.bollinger_hband()
     closes['bb_l'] = bb.bollinger_lband()
```

What's the issue?
When using data from yfinance it works normally, but when using the binance API data it fails and shows the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I don't understand the nature of this error as i am not comparing a dataframe with anything at all, i was expecting to have this error when for example building an if statement and using dataframe as a statement to be compared.

Anyway, do you have any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: read this post [(truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) and chk your code by yourself. If you want to ask someone else's opinion, please read the notice and provide [mre].